# php shell_exec uses bourne shell regardless of what i am doing

Tags: php, command-line-interface

when i call shell_exec as the following, it doesn't actually call the php but does sh: and file not found.

```
shell_exec('"/usr/bin/php ./magento xigen:clicreatecustomer:create -f \"' . $contacts['name'] . '\" -l \"company\" -e \" ' . $contacts['email'] . '\" -p \"test123\" -w 1 --street \"' . $address['Address1'] . '\" --city \"' . $address['City'] . '\" --region \" ' . $address['State'] .' \" --telephone \"00000000\" --postcode \" '. $address['Zip'].' \" -c \"' . $customer['entityid'] . '"');
```

what am I doing wrong? i have tried doing absolute paths also.

Comment: Surely this module gives you a method you can call directly from PHP so that you don't have to do PHP to shell_exec to bash to PHP to a CLI wrapper to a method?

Comment: nope, sadly it doesn't. its a CLI command to begin with. aka meant to be ran from the command line.I have approx 4k addresses to enter and this was just a shortcut since all i receive is a json file.

Comment: Is it this? https://www.axigen.com/documentation/cli-api/

Comment: @AlexHowansky no. can we just stick with the original question I had please?

Comment: @lostnconfused a word to the wise, seeing as you're new here - you are *asking for help*. You should, as they say, help us help you; and that includes e.g. telling us where the script comes from, what messages you receive, and so on, rather than forcing us to guess. After all, there are so many other questions one could answer rather than yours; it is in your best interest to make helping you as pleasant and rewarding as possible.
(See e.g. ESR's *smart questions*: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html )

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path to `magento` in your command, that could be what `sh` is choking on.

EDIT:

Two things:

1. Try `echo`ing one line from your script and executing it from the shell manually to determine where your shell command is failing. This may help solve your problem entirely.
2. If you are still having problems running the code through PHP, instead of running the commands through `shell_exec`, write them all to a separate file, then `source` that file from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding too many quote signs.

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/php ./magento xigen:clicreatecustomer:create -f '{$contacts['name']}' -l company -e '{$contacts['email']}' -p 'test123' -w 1 --street '{$address['Address1']}' --city '{$address['City']}' --region '{$address['State']}' --telephone '00000000' --postcode '{$address['Zip']}' -c '{$customer['entityid']}'";

shell_exec($cmd);
```

Therefore, the shell tried to execute a file called "/usr/bin/php\ ./magento\ xigen...", and that file, of course, does not exist.

Note that if the address or any other field contains an unquoted single quote, the command will fail. You need to replace "'" with "\'" in those fields before running the command.

To debug what is happening, print the contents of the `$cmd` variable, or save it to a file and inspect it.

Comment: sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
the quotes are for the arguements as dictated by the cli command.

Comment: Unless there are strange signs in the variables, the syntax should be correct. Adding some debugging...

Comment: I did a little testing and found out its the echo that i was missing. the problem being is that the arguments need to be inclosed in quotation marks aka ". how can we get that to happen?

Comment: @lostnconfused that can't be right: the quote marks are **not** passed on to the script by PHP, i.e., the magento command has no way of knowing *how* its arguments were quoted. `-p 12345`, `-p '12345'` and `-p "12345"` all pass to the target the two strings `-p` and `12345`.
It is more likely that you aren't following the syntax of Dominic Watts' `xigen:clicreatecustomer:create` script.
Try including in your question the output of `$cmd` as I suggested, and also **any error messages that you receive now**, and let's see.

Comment: it does if the text might be multiple words yes? like what might be given for an address?

Comment: @lostnconfused Yes and no. If you put in the command line the five characters `"a b"`, then the PHP script will receive one argument containing the three characters `a b`. The quote signs necessary to this are already in the answer, you needn't add more. However, you can do so - just escape them: the nine characters `"\"a b\""` will be received as the five characters `"a b"`.

Comment: my problem is that the cli requires the quotations in it. aka I need to accommodate that also in this respect.

Comment: @lostnconfused look... you chose to not share any more information - no error messages, no package information, no platform details, *nothing*, not even when explicitly asked - and I respect that. However, you have to accept that this severely limits any suggestions I might give.